# How to prepend colon (:) and append (,) array values in php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create simple PDO mysql insert query statement in most clean and efficient way.

**My question is that, is there any simple function in php that could both append and prepend array values and convert it to a string like implode() function do? Or am i doing it right-(See last working code i provided)**

Correct me if i am wrong, implode just adds a single string inbetween each value before converting to a string.Hope my code will clear out more what i am trying to achieve.

```
//key as field name value as value
$field_values=array(
"firstname"=>$fname,
"lastname"=>$lname,
"phone"=>$phone);

 //field name would work fine as just a comma is appended to each array key
 //i need,if there is  an inline way to perform array values to start with colon and end with comma.
 //this doesn't work as not comma is added inbetween

 $sql="INSERT INTO student (".implode(",",array_keys($field_values).") VALUES (".implode(":",$field_values).")";

 //result wrong no commas
 //INSERT INTO student (firstname,lastname,phone) VALUES (:firstname:lastname:phone);
 //i want this
 //INSERT INTO student (firstname,lastname,phone) VALUES (:firstname,:lastname,:phone);
```

i can't use this too

```
$sql="INSERT INTO student (".implode(",",array_keys($field_values).") VALUES (?,?,?);
```

i am using this to bind

```
foreach($field_values as $field=>$value)
{
    $dbh->bindValue(':'.$field,$value);
}
```

I know i could achieve this with just writing a string like `:firstname,:lastname,:phone` or may be with regex or use a foreach loop to append and prepend like this.*This would work fine but its lengthy*

```
    $fv="";
    foreach($field_values as $field=>$value)
    {
        $fv.=":".$field.",";
    }
    $fv=rtrim($fv, ",");
    $sql="INSERT INTO student (".implode(",",$field_values).") VALUES (".$fv.")";
```

But what i want to know whether there is a way to do that something like the code i used above. in the scenario the array keys may change, so i am searching for a dynamic efficient way.

Help me please :)
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if down voted please let me know why? :) why is random downvoting a habit here :/

Comment: No such thing as random down voting on stack overflow (the bots pick it up and reverse it if it happens). I don't see why your question should be down voted so have an up vote to balance it

Comment: thanx @RobbieAverill :)

Comment: But why would you do that

Comment: to create sql string like this  "INSERT INTO testtable(name, lastname, age)
    VALUES(:fname, :sname, :age)" :)

Comment: Relevant question, should not be down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

This PDO Insert function will accept an array as input.

```
// Insert an array with key-value pairs into a specified MySQL database table.
function pdo_insert($dbh,$table,$keyvals) {
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s ( `%s` ) %sVALUES ( :%s );",
        $table,
        implode("`, `", array_keys($keyvals)), 
        implode(", :", array_keys($keyvals))
    );
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($keyvals as $field => $value) {
        $stmt->bindValue(":$field", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    return $dbh->lastInsertId();
}

// Convert special characters to HTML safe entities.
function h($str) {
    return trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')));
}
```

Example:

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$keyvals = [                
    'id' => isset($_POST['id']) ? h( $_POST['id'] ) : null, 
    'title' => isset($_POST['title']) ? h( $_POST['title'] ) : null,    
    'description' => isset($_POST['description']) ? h( $_POST['description'] ) : null,
    'created_at' => time(),
    'created_by' => 1,
];
$last_ids[] = pdo_insert($dbh,'products',$keyvals);
```

Comment: This function is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: @YourCommonSense is it?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Fixed. Btw, I was actually having your SafeMySQL script in mind when making this pdo_insert function.

Answer (score -1):

if you dont want to use a foreach to add in the : for the column names you can try something like this

```
$fname = "first";
$lname = "last";
$phone = "2342344";
$field_values=array(
"firstname"=>$fname,
"lastname"=>$lname,
"phone"=>$phone
);

echo  "INSERT INTO student (`:".implode("`,:`",$field_values)."`) VALUES (".$fv.")";
```

as you can see in the insert columns i added a `: to the being and end in the columns bracket

Comment: You bind values not column names